# Unicode symbol (25be) not displaying on Samsung mini devices

Tags: android, css, unicode, icon-fonts

I've included an iconfont and I'm trying to use Unicode symbols as the characters for the icons. Most seem to be working except for a couple on the site which return blank.

25be and 25b4 seem to be the main ones.

I'm loading these as content in a pseudo element like so:

```
  content: '\25b4';
```

It works fine on most browsers but not Chrome on the Samsung Mini S3 and also Galaxy S4

Comment: How about `\u25b4` ?

Comment: I think they're the same symbol but for html you have to remove the `u` on this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is some information on browser support for this symbol here:

http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/25BE/

It looks like you need to include it via a font-face declaration on Samsung devices.